# Is there a possibility to "pimp" Putty in order to generate logs automatically and run multiple sessions in one windows (similar Linux "Terminal")?

Tags: ssh, logging, putty, serial

I'm using Putty for Serial or SSH connections to systems.

For every session, I need to configure Logging manually, enter a new name and destination.
I was wondering if there was a solution to set it automatically. Maybe some genius wrote a plugin that's able to do it. Even better would be if Putty will ask you where to save the log right after closing a session window.

My second question is regarding the multiple sessions. Is it possible to open sessions in tabs, a little bit like the Linux terminal?

Otherwise, is there another tool that can be used under Windows and allowing all of the above?
Even a shareware.

Comment: Iain: why did you remove the "thanks" line from the post?

Comment: Hi and Thanks are often removed, as per: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876

Comment: I cannot agree with this kind of moderation philosophy and would expect moderation to intervene only where absolutely necessary - explicitly not on a regular basis because of formatting issues or to "fix" the original wording. But I suppose this is rather a cultural issue of "newsgroup kiddies" advocating their freedom to post nonsense against "forum kiddies" who see a different quality of participation and try to keep the site clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logging is pretty easy, and built into putty.  Under "Putty Configuration" click "Session", "Logging".  Choose what you want to log, and where.  Use the variables &Y &M &D &T &H: year, month, day, time and host.  I suggest something like:

&T&D&M&Y&H.log

So it's easy to sort.

SecureCRT gives you tabs, but it's not free:

http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I know the logging system from Putty, but it's not satisfaying me, that's why I asked if there was something I didn't know... But the variables are interesting, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on why this doesn't work for you.  It creates a new file for every session, automatically and even names the file whatever you want.  It sounds like you just want a prompt on logoff?

Comment: No that's perfect, thanks! I never used it before, it's actually what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

For tab, there's [SuperPuTTY](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/superputty-windows-gui-application-that-can-open-putty-ssh-client-in-tabs/).

Comment: Looks nice. That web page seems so spammy though. Is that the authors site?

Comment: Nope. Just an explanation. The "Download SuperPuTTY" link at the bottom of the page probably goes to the author's site, though.

Comment: Thanks! It looks really great, but I can't find any download link... yet!

Comment: The blog's download link ends up at some other almost-as-spammy site.  The project is at https://github.com/phendryx/superputty

Comment: Actually, it seems there are *two* active superputty projects, the github one is a fork of http://code.google.com/p/superputty/ claiming it was abandoned, but the googlecode project seems pretty active to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Found it, and tested it... it's nice, but I let myself seduced from SecureCRT, great software! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google would have saved you the effort of asking and waiting for an answer. [This blog post](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/get-tabs-for-your-putty/) about the [Putty connection manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/puttycm/) (which has admittedly moved in the meantime) was among the first hits on my search and is already 3 years old.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but Google is not my friend... ;-)

Comment: s/Google/<search engine of your choice>/. But reading about the logging host/date variables were worth it nonetheless.

Comment: I can only find the following message: "This project has no files." Do you have another link? I keep looking (with Google...) further. Thanks.

Comment: The old site at free.fr still hosts the download as it appears: http://puttycm.free.fr/download/puttycm.exe

Comment: Great! Vielen vielen Dank!